# Save current windows theme to vsf file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, vcl-styles

How to save current windows 7 theme (default, aero) to Delphi style format (vsf file)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot save it, that is theme that is not drawn with help of VCL Styles, but by Windows itself.